# How to replace a line with a certain pattern in vi?

Tags: vi

I am trying to replace lines that contain the pattern `"s#_decoded_block["` with `"s#_decoded_block_"`. The command I am using to do that is

```
%s/s\d\+_decoded_block\[/s\d\+_decoded_block_/g
```

I expect to get `"s#_decoded_block_"` as substitutions but instead I am getting `"sd+_decoded_block_"`. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to expect a decimal number for "#" in the question.  You can do this using a backreference:

```
%s/s\(\d\+\)_decoded_block\[/s\1_decoded_block_/g
```

where `\(\d\+\)` matches one or more decimal digits and is replaced using the marker `\1`.

You could improve the backreference by moving more of the text inside it:

```
%s/s\(\d\+_decoded_block\)\[/s\1_/g
```

because `\1` will be replaced by whatever was matched in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it perfectly fits your use case, but it looks like you may as well just use:

```
:g/s\d\+_decoded_block\[/ s/\[/_/
```

...unless there are potentially other `[` characters in the matching lines *preceding* the one you want to change.

Simpler is better, *if* it fits your requirements.